# How is the size of structures with bit-fields are calculated which contains some unnamed members and zero sized bit-fields?

Tags: c, struct, unions, bit-fields

How the size of this struct is calculated :

```
struct B {
    unsigned char c1 : 1;
    unsigned char : 2;
    unsigned char c2 : 2;
    unsigned char : 0;
    unsigned char c3 : 4;
    unsigned char c4 : 1;
};
```

What does this `0` stands for here?, does that mean that it is occupying 0-bits (i.e. no memory)

Can someone explain this to me that how its size is being calculated?

Comment: The unnamed bit field of size zero can be forced to break up padding

Comment: @IrAM does the memory for structure is assigned in the order the members are written (i.e. moving from top to the bottom)?

Comment: The ordering of bit-fields and just about everything about them is [entirely implementation-defined and non-portable](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p11): "An implementation may allocate **any addressable storage unit** large enough to hold a bit- field. If enough space remains, a bit-field that immediately follows another bit-field in a structure shall be packed into adjacent bits of the same unit. If insufficient space remains, whether a bit-field that does not fit is put into the next unit or overlaps adjacent units is **implementation-defined**. ...

Comment: (cont) ... The order of allocation of bit-fields within a unit (high-order to low-order or low-order to high-order) is **implementation-defined**. The alignment of the addressable storage unit **is unspecified**."  So without details of the C compiler and OS you're using, you won't be able to get a complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

A bit-field of size 0 is used to specify that any following bit-fields are to be placed in a separate byte / unit.  So the layout of the struct would probably look like this:

```
| c1|       |   c2  |           |      c3       | c4|           |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|  0|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|  7|  8|  9| 10| 11| 12| 13| 14| 15|
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Without the field of size 0, it would probably look like this:

```
| c1|       |   c2  |      c3       | c4|                       |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|  0|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|  7|  8|  9| 10| 11| 12| 13| 14| 15|
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Note however that the ordering of bit-fields in a struct is implementation defined, so it might not look exactly like this.

Comment: The question does not ask for the layout of the structure, except for the effect of the `: 0`. It asks how the size is calculated.

Answer (score 1):

A bit-field length of `0` means *start a new storage unit*.

One possible layout for the structure in the question is:

- an initial storage unit for member `c1`, an unnamed member of length 2 and member `c2`,
- a separate storage unit for members `c3` and `c4`.

Both of these storage units can be as small as a single byte as each contains only 5 bits of information, making `struct B` a 2-byte object, ie: `sizeof(struct B) == 2`. But other sizes are possible, as the choice of storage unit is implementation defined and extra padding between members and at the end of the structure is also possible. Any size greater than `2` is possible. It is arguable that a size of `1` is not possible even on architectures where a byte can store at least 10 bits, because 2 storage units are required by the `unsigned char : 0;` member specification.

Here are the definitions from the C Standard:

> **6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers**
>
> **Contraints**
> [...]
> <sup>4</sup> The expression that specifies the width of a bit-field shall be an integer constant expression with a nonnegative value that does not exceed the width of an object of the type that would be specified were the colon and expression omitted. If the value is zero, the declaration shall have no declarator.
>
> <sup>5</sup> A bit-field shall have a type that is a qualified or unqualified version of `_Bool`, `signed int`, `unsigned int`, or some other implementation-defined type. It is implementation-defined whether atomic types are permitted.
>
> **Semantics**
> [...]
> <sup>9</sup> A member of a structure or union may have any complete object type other than a variably modified type. In addition, a member may be declared to consist of a specified number of bits (including a sign bit, if any). Such a member is called a bit-field; its width is preceded by a colon.
>
> <sup>10</sup> A bit-field is interpreted as having a signed or unsigned integer type consisting of the specified number of bits. If the value 0 or 1 is stored into a nonzero-width bit-field of type `_Bool`, the value of the bit-field shall compare equal to the value stored; a `_Bool` bit-field has the semantics of a `_Bool`.
>
> <sup>11</sup> An implementation may allocate any addressable storage unit large enough to hold a bit-field. If enough space remains, a bit-field that immediately follows another bit-field in a structure shall be packed into adjacent bits of the same unit. If insufficient space remains, whether a bit-field that does not fit is put into the next unit or overlaps adjacent units is implementation-defined. The order of allocation of bit-fields within a unit (high-order to low-order or low-order to high-order) is implementation-defined. The alignment of the addressable storage unit is unspecified.
>
> <sup>12</sup> A bit-field declaration with no declarator, but only a colon and a width, indicates an unnamed bit-field. As a special case, a bit-field structure member with a width of `0` indicates that no further bit-field is to be packed into the unit in which the previous bit-field, if any, was placed.

Hence it is implementation defined how `c1` and `c2` are placed within their common storage unit, and the same goes for `c3` and `c4`.  <sup>10</sup> implies that the choice of allocation unit be implementation defined, therefore the size of `struct B` is also implementation defined: it could be `2`, `4`, `8`, etc. As a matter of fact, the storage units do not need to have the same size and padding is permitted so any size greater than `1` is possible in theory.

The lack of a more precise and portable specification for bit-fields is quite counter-productive as these would be well tailored to map physical hardware devices. Differences in implementations in early C compilers and practical constraints related to endianness constraints prompted this flexibility in the specification and implementation variations especially regarding signed bit-fields made programmers reluctant to use this feature.

Comment: While the bit-fields require two storage units, hypothetically the size of the structure could be any integer greater than 1 because the C standard allows padding at the end of the structure, without constraint. Also, it is not clear to me whether the “storage unit” used for bit-fields has to be the same in each instance. If I have `struct foo { int a : 3, b : 5, c : 30 };`, could the implementation put `a` and `b` in a byte and `c` in a four-byte unit?

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I agree with you. the alignment is also implementation defined, so packing `a` and `b` in a byte and storing `c` in an adjacent 32-bit word is possible albeit unlikely. Whether `c` straddles across two 32-bit units is also implementation defined.